# Invoker ultimate(DOTA 2) combination... How is it calculated?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

While playing DOTA 2 with invoker I thought how the total combination of his ultimate calculated.

Description:

He has 9 element. lets say 3(blue) , 3 (pink) and 3(yellow) . Every time he can choose 3 element from there. How many way is there to pick? Answer is 10. I didn't get it.

A dumb question to start with sorry for that.

[Here is the picture with all combination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6m6a.jpg)

Comment: Try this on math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You will have to find a more appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: sorry and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution for this is calculated using [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) (Theorem 2 on Wikipedia).

For `n = k = 3`, you get `C(n+k-1,n) = C(3+3-1,3-1) = C(5,2) = 10`.

Comment: short but precise answer!! Like 3 balls into 3 different boxes and empty box is allowed